# basic java for mobile development

Tags: java

Good day!

Is it possible to create mobile games or services just knowing Java SE / J2EE? I applied for a job with a mobile service company and they only require Java SE / J2EE knowledge and they told me that this are what we are going to use. How is this possible?  From my understanding, Java mobile applications should be created using J2ME.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Android runs kind of JAVA SE, not the ME variant. So there is no problem I think.

Comment: They will probably be doing training on the job to get you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Mobile applications are different. Some are developed with Objective-C(iOs), some with pure Java(not absolutely pure, but - that's Android case). J2ME is just an option.
2. Some mobile applications are special web-pages developed specially for mobiles. HTML5 is a good technology now and it is supported by modern mobile browsers(Safari and Chrome mobile).

So, yes. You can develop mobile applications without knowledge of j2me.